# How to get URLs for requests currently served by Nginx?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, command-line-interface

As the title explains, I want to know the URLs for requests that are currently being served by Nginx, all the answers regarding nginx_status endpoint talk about the **number** of requests, if possible I want to list the requests **URLs**. This is possible with apache, I have a WHM server and in the Apache status page, I can see URLs for all requests.

I'm using Nginx 1.14.0 on Ubuntu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135719/full-record-url-in-nginx-log?
You can record request URLs in access logs and then write a program in go/python/shell to scrape URLs from this.

Comment: I'm assuming requests are only stored in the log AFTER the request is finished, which is not what I'm looking for, I want to check a list of URLs for requests currently being processed.

Answer (score 0):

To show the full url, add the following

```
log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                '"$request_method $scheme://$host$request_uri $server_protocol" '
                '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                '"$http_user_agent" $request_time';
```

If you are behind reverse proxy, replace $remote_addr with $http_x_forwarded_for
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html?&_ga=2.151893182.625836960.1700471825-1055325474.1700471825#log_format